# Spanish - German Dictionary under free licence

Tags: spanish, german, dictionary, software

I am looking for a German - Spanish (or Spanish - German) dictionary, that can be downloaded (if possible for free) in raw-format, to be used in a software application.

Does anyone know relevant resources?

Comment: There is dict.cc, but the site says there are conditions on the use of the data in an application. It says you can't include the data in the application itself, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[WikiDict](https://www.wikdict.com/) offers [downloads](https://www.wikdict.com/page/download) of dictionaries licensed under [Creative Commons BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which doesn't prohibit commercial use. [Spanish to German](https://download.wikdict.com/dictionaries/sqlite/2_2024-01/es-de.sqlite3) and [German to Spanish](https://download.wikdict.com/dictionaries/sqlite/2_2024-01/de-es.sqlite3) are both available, along with dozens of others.